# Unloading dll throws an Access violation error

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, dll

So I have this dll:

```cpp
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

HMODULE myhModule;

DWORD __stdcall EjectThread(LPVOID lpParameter) {
    Sleep(100);
    FreeLibraryAndExitThread(myhModule,0);
}

DWORD WINAPI MainThread(LPVOID param) // our main thread
{
    AllocConsole(); // enables the console
    freopen("CONIN$", "r", stdin); // makes it possible to output to output to console with cout.
    freopen("CONOUT$", "w", stdout);
    while (true) {
        Sleep(100);
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DELETE) & 1) {
            cout << "[+] Attempting dll unload" << endl;
            Sleep(800);
            break;
        }
    }
    FreeConsole();
    CreateThread(NULL, 0, EjectThread, NULL, 0, 0);
    return false;
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
    if(ul_reason_for_call == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {// gets runned when injected
        myhModule = hModule;
        CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)MainThread, NULL, 0, 0); // creates our main thread 
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

*Explanation*:

When the dll is loaded we are creating an `myhModule` variable to be able to assign to it the base address of our dll, then we Create a mainthread which will create a thread calling the ejectThread function which should unload the dll using `myhModule` and the `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` method when the `VK_DELETE` key is pressed.

*Steps and error experienced*:

So I'm injecting my dll inside a process with an injector, then if the Delete key is pressed it unloads the dll, however I get an access violation error telling me that I cannot access the process at a memory location.

*Error*:

```cpp
Exception thrown at 0x1CD62194 in process.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation executing location 0x1CD62194.
```

What did I do wrong here, why does it throw an `access violation` error?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You're unloading the DLL while the thread is still running. That means the code it is executing no longer exists. Use `FreeLibraryAndExitThread()` if you want to exit your thread and unload your DLL safely.

Comment: @JonathanPotter Thank you for your response however even with freelibraryandexiThread I get the same error

Comment: @Alex It is not safe to call `CreateThread` inside of DllMain.  [See this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices)

Comment: You shouldn't need to cast functions. If the compiler is giving trouble, fix the function declaration. Otherwise, remove the redundant cast since it causes suspicion.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - this is absolute safe and correct

Comment: @RbMm I just linked to the document.  Convince the OP that it is safe, given the document I linked to.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - and so what ? documentation here not best. however call `CreateThread` form dll entry point - **absolute safe and correct**, even this not best documentation agree with this

Comment: Again, I'm not saying you're wrong, just that it would give me some pause if I read that document on their website.  Not everyone links to StackOverflow first if they are curious about DLLMain safety -- they will go or find that MS site first.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - i know better than this very bad article. call thread thread is absolute safe and correct. no any problems here. error - is **wait** for thread.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie *creating* a thread in `DllMain` is safe. *Synchronizing* with a thread in `DllMain` is not. The MSDN document in question says as much.

Comment: @pau: [Does creating a thread from DllMain deadlock or doesn't it?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070904-00/?p=25283)

Comment: @IInspectable hello, thank you for your article however in my new program I used 
`DisableThreadLibraryCalls`

Comment: The comment was meant to augment the recommendations posted by @PaulMcKenzie earlier, by providing rationale to understand, when deviating from the official best practices is safe. I'm not sure I understand the relevance of calling `DisableThreadLibraryCalls`. That call in particular has had a bad history, by preventing some versions of the CRT from properly initializing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quouting RbMm's answer:

> when thread is exit - we must free reference to DLL - this is done via FreeLibraryAndExitThread. and this need do for every dll thread.

I think what happnes, is that your `EjectThread` actually susccsessfully unloads DLL and exits. BUT, you `MainThread` is still running at this time! So what happens next, it tries to do one of it's function calls and uses memory from DLL that no longer exists, which causes access violation. I had same error in my own program. What you need to do is `WaitForSingleObject` instead of using timeout of 100 ms. Somehow (I'm not sure how) its not enough time for `MainThread` to exit. Maybe because of console?

Answer (score 2):

when you create thread from DLL - of course DLL must not be unloaded while thread running. you need add reference to DLL before create thread. this can be done via call [`GetModuleHandleExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandleexw) function. when thread is exit - we must free reference to DLL - this is done via [`FreeLibraryAndExitThread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-freelibraryandexitthread). and this need do for **every** dll thread.

so code for create thread in general must be next

```
ULONG CreateThreadInDLL(PTHREAD_START_ROUTINE StartAddress, PVOID Parameter, PHANDLE phThread = 0, PDWORD pThreadId = 0)
{
    HMODULE hModule;
    if (GetModuleHandleExW(GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS, (PCWSTR)StartAddress, &hModule))
    {
        if (HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(0, 0, StartAddress, Parameter, 0, pThreadId))
        {
            if (phThread) *phThread = hThread; else CloseHandle(hThread);
            return NOERROR;
        }
        ULONG dwError = GetLastError();
        FreeLibrary(hModule);
        return dwError;
    }

    return GetLastError();
}
```

and in the end of thread must be call to

```
FreeLibraryAndExitThread((HMODULE)&__ImageBase,0);
```

if you want self unload DLL - create thread direct via `CreateThread` without call `GetModuleHandleExW` before it and in the end of thread call `FreeLibraryAndExitThread`.

with your concrete code you not need `EjectThread` at all, but exit from `MainThread` with `FreeLibraryAndExitThread((HMODUE)&__ImageBase,0);`  and not call `GetModuleHandleExW` ( `CreateThreadInDLL` need if you create several additional threads and can exit from main thread (with DLL unload) without wait on this thread termination)

```
DWORD WINAPI MainThread(LPVOID param) // our main thread
{
    // do something...
    FreeLibraryAndExitThread((HMODULE)&__ImageBase,0);
    return 0; //never executed really
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
    DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
    LPVOID lpReserved
)
{
    if(ul_reason_for_call == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH) {// gets runned when injected
        myhModule = hModule;
        CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)MainThread, NULL, 0, 0); // creates our main thread 
        return TRUE;
    }
    return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response however this does not fix my error, whenever I call FreeLibraryAndExitThread in my ejectthread function I get an access violation error.

Comment: @Alex - in this case you have error in some else place. need look stack trace and more info. however you not need create `EjectThread` at all. you need only `FreeLibraryAndExitThread` in the end on `MainThread` and you need understand dll reference counting and use debugger

Comment: so Now I don't have the error because I directly exit the thread inside main, however that closes the process aswell without returning an error, and it keeps the console open, do you have an idea on why?

Comment: @Alex - i not have your binary code and can not debug it. at first - not open/close console - this is very bad (faster of all this produce error)

Comment: Oh ok @RbMm let me try to remove the console.

Comment: I don't know why but it still crashes, without any errors.

Comment: @Alex because need use debugger

Comment: I'm using the debugger but nothing is output, it just closes the process with no errors

Comment: I tried adding breakpoints but it says that no symbols were loaded

Comment: @Alex Have you checked the event viewer to see if there is an event about crashed application?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT - for what need look event viewer when need use debugger ?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT @RbMm I did not, the problem here is I attach visual studio to a process I want to debug, then I inject my dll inside this process but even though I injected it and I created a new thread I tells me that the breakpoints won't work because the symbols were not loaded in the file. I also saw in the debug console that the process exited with code 0 with an error `0xC0000005`(Access violation) which tells me that I am accessing a wild pointer, which I don't really understand because I'm successfully exiting my main thread...

Comment: @Alex no any problem debug code. all what need - binary dll file